# Set the first tr to fixed without losing the width

Tags: css, html-table, fixed-header-tables

this is my fiddlejs: [https://jsfiddle.net/uj8gbeL1/]

Im trying to make fixed the first row of the table, but when i try to set the style `postion:fixed`, this row has a different width

How can i fix this issues without setting a "static" width to every th element?

Comment: Please read how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) preferably in a [Stack snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: @TimothyAlexisVass its not working when i scroll the page

Comment: oh, with google chrome doen't work, i tried with firefox and its ok. How can i do the same on chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will solve this by using:
`<tr class="globalTr" style="position:sticky;top:0;z-index:1">`

Or better, put it in the css:

```
.globalTr:first-child {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1; 
}
```

However, your code could be formatted a lot better.
Here is an example, please read the comments in the html:

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

table {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

th, td {
  border: 1px solid #369;
  padding: 10px;
}

th {
  background: #369;
  color: white;
}

td {
  background: aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Heading1</th> <!-- th is for headings -->
        <th>Heading2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <!-- use thead and tbody -->
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td> <!-- td is for cells -->
        <td>Content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: i tryed it, but, when i scroll the page, its doesn't work

Comment: oh, with google chrome doen't work, i tried with firefox and its ok. How can i do the same on chrome?

Comment: @user222137 I have updated the answer with a [Stack snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) including comments to help you.

Comment: oh realy thanks, now i understand how it works. Thanks you again

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS `position:sticky;top:0;` instead of `position:fixed;`.